# Rails scope with polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am getting some strange results from a very basic scope on a model with a polymorphic relationship.  Here's the brief summary and detail of the relationships.

models/financials.rb

```
class Financial < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :financiable, :polymorphic => true
  #ltm is a boolean field in the model
  scope :ltm,  -> { where(ltm: true).last }
```

And then there's a basic Firm model that has many financials

models/firm.rb

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :financials, :as => :financiable, dependent: :destroy
```

So I get a bizarre result when a `firm` has no ltm financials (i.e. no financials with `ltm: true`).  But when I call `firm.financials.ltm`  I get an activerecord relation of financials that belong to the firm but do NOT have ltm: true.  However, when I just do `firm.financials.where(ltm: true).last` I get `nil`

Summary of results for when there are no ltm financials for the firm:

```
firm.financials.ltm #AR relation of financials that belong to the firm but are not ltm
firm.financials.where(ltm: true).last #nil
```

And what makes it even stranger is that when a firm does have ltm financials, the scope works as expected.

Has anyone ever had this problem before or have any ideas?  I mean the easy answer is to not use the scope but I wanted to understand what could be causing this.

**---UPDATES BASED ON COMMENTS---**
Thank you guys for putting a lot of thought into this.

1. D-side You were correct.  The code was `firm.financials.ltm` and not `firm.financials.ltm.last`.  That was a typo when I typed up the question. I updated the above to reflect and also below are the SQL queries.
2. Jiří Pospíšil - Great advice.  I will update in my app but leave the same here so as not to create confusion.
3. Chumakoff.  I force ltm to false if the user doesn't enter true with a before_save call so I don't think this is it but thanks for the thought.

So these are from the scenario where `firm` doesn't have any `financials` with ltm = true.  As you can see, the scope request is making a second query to the database for all financials belonging to firm.  Why is it doing that when it can't find it in the initial query?

> firm.financials.ltm
>
> Financial Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "financials".* FROM "financials" 
>   WHERE "financials"."financiable_id" = $1 AND
>   "financials"."financiable_type" = $2 AND "financials"."ltm" = 't' 
>   ORDER BY "financials"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["financiable_id", 11],
>   ["financiable_type", "Firm"]]
>   Financial Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "financials".* FROM "financials"  WHERE
>   "financials"."financiable_id"= $1 AND "financials"."financiable_type"
>   = $2  [["financiable_id", 11], ["financiable_type", "Firm"]]
>
> firm.financials.where(ltm: true).last
>
> Financial Load (16.8ms)  SELECT  "financials".* FROM "financials" 
>   WHERE "financials"."financiable_id" = $1 AND
>   "financials"."financiable_type" = $2 AND "financials"."ltm" = 't' 
>   ORDER BY "financials"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["financiable_id", 11],
>   ["financiable_type", "Firm"]]

Comment: Resulting SQL queries would be helpful.

Comment: ...and hang on, do you really have `.last` finishing your scope? That wouldn't work with the code below at all. Please review the question and correct the code.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem but I'd strongly advise not to use the same name for the scope as for the attribute itself. The scope might even read better with a name like `with_ltm`.

Comment: Probably the cause of the problem might be that there are ltm=nil values in DB. If it is so, be sure that ltm has either true or false value.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I updated the question after reading your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope is not working correctly, `.last` in your scope get one results instead of an ActiveRecord relation, remove `.last` and the scope will work fine in getting all `Financials` with `ltm=true`